# Available apps for sending text in Android, Samsung default sms app issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

Im trying to target Whatsapp, Viber and default sms app on mobile phones to send some text from my app.

```
       `val whatsappIntent = Intent().apply {
        action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.")
        type = "text/plain"
        package = "com.whatsapp"
    }

    val viberIntent = Intent().apply {
        action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.")
        type = "text/plain"
        package = "com.viber.voip"
    }

    val smsIntent = Intent().apply {
        action = Intent.ACTION_SENDTO
        data = Uri.parse("smsto:")
        putExtra("sms_body", "This is my text to send.")
    }


    val intentList = listOf(whatsappIntent, viberIntent, smsIntent)

    val chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(Intent(), "Choose a messaging app")
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentList.toTypedArray())
    context.startActivity(chooserIntent)`
```

Main issuse happens on Samsung devices they wont open default SMS app only viber and whatsapp. I assume its because of this code:

```
  Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
```

Havent find solution yet

My code only opens Whatsapp and Viber but not default SMS app on Samsung phones. Tried on Xiaomi and default SMS app is shown.